# Array of Arrays JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

I'm having a problem with making a 2d array that stores user input and shows an error when the name that you enter for example is already stored in that array.

this is my program so far...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class a extends b{

    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception{

        String phonebook[][] = new String[2][];
        BufferedReader input = new BufferredReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        System.out.println("[1] Add contacts");
        System.out.println("[2] View all contacts");

        int choice = input.nextInt();
        selection(choice);
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class b{

    public static void selection(int choice){
    case 1: 


        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        phonebook[0][0] = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter landline or phone numbers: ");
        phonebook[0][1] = input.next();

        for(int x = 0; x < phonebook.length; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < phonebook[x].length ; y++){
            }
        }
        break;

    case 2: 
        show_phonebook(phonebook);
        break;

    default:

        System.out.println("ERROR");
        break;
    }

    public static void show_phonebook(String phonebook[][]){
        System.out.println(phonebook[x][y]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I know this code looks shit but I'm still a noob. I don't know how to do the error thing so a little help will be very grateful. Thanks

Comment: I am surprised that this code compiles (does it? x_X)

Comment: what error msg it shows?

Comment: Looks like your missing ```switch(choice)```. See: [The switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: yes.. you missed switch statement.

Comment: @Idos no it doesnt

Comment: Can you guys give me an idea on how to show an error when the user enters the same input? I really dont know how to do it

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651080/searching-a-2d-array-java-for-an-element

Answer (score 2):

1. Class names in Java Start with an Capital "A extends B"
2. I don't see a profit in inheriting another Class here. Define the methods in Class A
3. You will need a proper switch(argument) case: and so on....
4. showing all contancts should loop through the filled arrays.
5. For your error message solution: define a input string and try to check the indexes in the forloop equality: if(array [x][y].equals(input)){ code...}

Edit: you can make your check if "better" by first .toLowerCase the input and String at Array[x][y].toLowerCase -> the improvement would be that the user can check for MaRTin and if there was already an mArtIN stored, it will trigger.